# How to manipulate data frame as the example provided in the description using python

Tags: python

How can I have such a data frame using pandas?

```
  Name          Details
0 Roan          Male
                Student
                Single
1 Marry         Female
                Married
2 Ruth          Male
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the name column as index in pandas. You can read the documentation about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).